# ABC depreciated - where to inherit abstractmethod decorator from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, abstract-class, deprecation-warning

I am getting the following warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.9 it will stop working
    return isinstance(x, collections.Callable)
```

when I run my unit tests for my project. I replaced:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
```

with:

```
from collections.abc import Callable
from abc import abstractmethod
```

and am still getting the same warning. Is there somewhere else I should be importing `abstractmethod` from?

Comment: Please share the class definition (code).

Comment: I think the issue isn't with your imports, but with the line in your code `return isinstance(x, collections.Callable)`, which you need to replace with `return isinstance(x, collections.abc.Callable)` or `return isinstance(x, Callable)` (with `Callable` imported from `collections.abc`)

Comment: I use `from abc import abstractmethod, ABC` in my code and do not get the `DeprecationWarning`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with pytest. Check the warning message once again and make sure it is an issue with *your* imports. In my Python 3.7 environment it was some dependency package called pyreadlines that caused the error:

```
======== warnings summary ===============
C:\Users\Me\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\py3k_compat.py:8
C:\Users\Me\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\py3k_compat.py:8: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3,and in 3.9 it will stop working
return isinstance(x, collections.Callable)
-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
```

Unfortunately pyreadline was already "up-to-date" and only supports Python up to 3.5 so there's no need to blame the maintainers.

Replacing the import statement in that file as you described in you post fixed the issue for me.